# illegalArgumentException:node to traverse cannot be null

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

I sort for a solution perculiar to the problem i currently face with my code but didn't find any. I know someone out here can help. I need assistance please. I have a table in the database that keeps record of cities. Each city must belong to only one country but different cities existing in different countries could actually have the same name. I successfully add a city to the database through the form but my problem is when i retrieve one of the records from the database and try updating it, the form doesn't databind the country attribute. i tried printing out to the console and it says the country id is null. below are the codes
my controller code for the city:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/city")
public class CityController {

@Autowired
private CountriesService countryService;

@Autowired
private CitiesService cityService;

@RequestMapping("/manage")
public String manageCity(Model model){

    return"ManageCities";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String createCity(Model model){
    List<Countries> countryList=new ArrayList<Countries>();
    List<String> countryString=new ArrayList<>();
    countryString.add("Japan");
    model.addAttribute("cityModel", new Cities());
    model.addAttribute("countryList", countryService.searchAll());
    model.addAttribute("countryString",countryString);
    return"AddCity";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/post",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String postCity(@ModelAttribute("cityModel")Cities city){
    cityService.create(city);
    return"redirect:/city/manage";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/update",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCities(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("cityList", cityService.searchAll());
    return"UpdateCity";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/update/{cityId}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCityUpdateInfo(Model model,@PathVariable("cityId")Integer cityId,HttpSession session){
    session.setAttribute("cityId", cityId);
    model.addAttribute("cityModel", new Cities());
    model.addAttribute("cityObj", cityService.searchById(cityId));
    model.addAttribute("countryList",countryService.searchAll());
    return"CityInfo";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/update/{cityId}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateCityUpdate(@ModelAttribute("cityModel")Cities  city,HttpSession session){


    Integer i=(Integer)session.getAttribute("cityId");

    city.setCityCode(i);
    System.out.println(city);
    System.out.println(city.getCountryCode().toString());

    cityService.update(city);

    return "redirect:/city/update";
}

}
```

below is the query that runs the update:

```
@Repository
public class CitiesDaoImpl implements CitiesDao{
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "AirlineReservationSystemPU")
EntityManager em;
@Override
public void create(Cities a) {
    em.merge(a);
}

@Override
public void update(Cities a) {
    Query query=em.createQuery("update Cities c set c.cityName=:cityName, c.countryCode.countryCode=:countryCode"
            + "where c.cityCode=:cityCode");
    query.setParameter("cityName", a.getCityName());
    query.setParameter("countryCode", a.getCountryCode().getCountryCode());
    query.setParameter("cityCode", a.getCityCode());
    query.executeUpdate();
}

@Override
public void delete(Integer a) {
    Cities o=searchById(a);
    if(o!=null){
        em.remove(o);
    }
}

@Override
public Cities searchById(Integer Id) {
   return em.find(Cities.class, Id);
}

@Override
public List<Cities> searchAll() {
    Query query=em.createQuery("SELECT c From Cities c");
    List list=query.getResultList();
    return list;
}

}
```

below is the jsp form:

```
<%-- 
Document   : AddCountry
Created on : 23-May-2016, 9:15:38 AM
Author     : lami
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,  minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#3e454c">

    <title>Admin</title>

    <!-- Font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Sandstone Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Datatables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap social button library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap-social.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap select -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap-select.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap file input -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/fileinput.min.css">
    <!-- Awesome Bootstrap checkbox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css">
    <!-- Admin Stye -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/styles.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <%@include file="jspincludehead.jsp" %>
    <div class="ts-main-content">
        <%@include file="jspincludeMenu.jsp" %>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <h2 class="page-title">Add City</h2>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">City Add   Form</div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <spring:url  value="/city/update/{cityId}" var="city"/>
                                        <form:form action="${city}"  method="post" class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="cityModel">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">City Name</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <form:input path="cityName" type="text" class="form-control" value="${cityObj.getCityName()}" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="hr-dashed"></div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select Country</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <form:select path="countryCode.countryCode" class="selectpicker" >
                                                        <c:forEach items="${countryList}" var="st" varStatus="status">
                                                            <c:choose>
                                                                <c:when test="${st.getCountryCode() eq cityObj.getCountryCode().getCountryCode()}">
                                                                    <option value="<c:out value="${st.getCountryCode()}"/>" selected="true"> 
                                                                        <c:out value="${st.toString()}"/>
                                                                    <option>
                                                                </c:when>
                                                                <c:otherwise>
                                                                     <option value="<c:out value="${st.getCountryCode()}"/>"> 
                                                                        <c:out value="${st.toString()}"/>
                                                                    </option>
                                                                </c:otherwise>
                                                            </c:choose>

                                                        </c:forEach>
                                                    </form:select>



                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="hr-dashed"></div>
                                            <div class="form-group">

                                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-9">

                                                    <form:button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update City</form:button></div>
                                                </div>

                                        </form:form>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="clearfix pt pb">
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/fileinput.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/chartData.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/mains.js"></script>

    <script>

        window.onload = function () {

            // Line chart from swirlData for dashReport
            var ctx = document.getElementById("dashReport").getContext("2d");
            window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(swirlData, {
                responsive: true,
                scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
                scaleBeginAtZero: true

            });

            // Pie Chart from doughutData
            var doctx = document.getElementById("chart-area3").getContext("2d");
            window.myDoughnut = new Chart(doctx).Pie(doughnutData, {responsive: true});

            // Dougnut Chart from doughnutData
            var doctx = document.getElementById("chart-area4").getContext("2d");
            window.myDoughnut = new Chart(doctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {responsive: true});

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

each time i click on the update button it throws this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:64)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:300)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:257)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1368.createQuery(Unknown Source)
com.ars.application.dao.AirportsDaoImpl.update(AirportsDaoImpl.java:31)
com.ars.application.service.AirportsServiceImpl.update(AirportsServiceImpl.java:33)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1373.update(Unknown Source)
com.ars.application.controllers.AirportController.postAirportInfo(AirportController.java:77)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

i tried printing to the console and realised that the spring isnt binding the countryCode field to the entity. any possible sugggestion is welcomed please. thanks

Comment: "c.countryCode.countryCode=:countryCode" ... but you don't post what is c.countryCode (or even what are any of the Entities). Spring has nothing to do with it (nor does the JSP, or Spring binding) ... that is Hibernate handing the JPQL ... the JPA provider.

Comment: Thanks Neil. what i was trying to do by that code was to set the country's unique id in the cities object which was meant to be delivered as a request parameter from the form to the controller. but as it stands  it delivers null to the controller method and not the countryCode that the <option> tag suppose to deliver as its value